# Can vs.net create public properties from private members using its Refactoring?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have like 10 private members in my class, and I was hoping vs.net could create public properties from them but can't seem to find that option in VS.NET 2008.

Is there a feature for this?

Comment: What language are you using? Code Completion should make it extremely easy to do this even if refactoring doesn't. 10 properties should take under five minutes.

Comment: and that is 5 minutes too much, especially when this is such a common task....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS, select the field you want to create a property for.  In the Refactor menu select Encapsulate Field... and in the Encapsulate Field dialog which appears enter the name for the property and click OK.

You'll have to do this for each field, but it's pretty quick (especially if you use shortcut keys).

Comment: thanks, that's at least better than doing 100% manual.  Very surprised they don't have this out of the box. guess it makes jetbrains richer!

Comment: BTW, what is the shortcut key to open encapsulate field window?

Comment: On my machine Control+R, E.  You can also show the shortcuts on the tooltips by selecting Tools > Customize and checking 'Show shortcut keys in Screentips'